# Excel Marco - How to combine and name datasets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to consolidate data from a list of file paths into one worksheet then add the names per dataset.  I have a list of names and paths set up like this in Excel:

Name1, Path1
Name2, Path2
Name3, Path3

The macro I have written so far loops through the paths, copy and paste into the master spreadsheet starting in the first empty in column B.  What I want the macro to also do is also fill in column A with Name1, Name2, and Name3 next to the respective dataset.  I got the macro do to the first part but now I can't get it to do the naming part.  Here is my code so far:

```
Sub Data()

Dim ws As Worksheet, dataws As Worksheet
Dim wkb As Workbook, wkbFrom As Workbook
Dim wkblist As Range
Dim fromtab As String
Dim Name As String

For Each wkblist In Sheets("Ref").Range("d4:d18")
If wkblist.Value = "" Then
Exit For
Else

Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
Set wkbFrom = Workbooks.Open(wkblist)
Set ws = wkb.Sheets("Ref")
Set dataws = wkb.Sheets("Data")

fromtab = ws.Range("b22")

wkbFrom.Worksheets(fromtab).Range("b2:z200").Copy
dataws.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlValues


Application.CutCopyMode = False
wkbFrom.Close

End If
Next wkblist

End Sub
```

Comment: Are the names in `Sheets("Ref").Range("C4:C18")`?

Comment: Yes, exactly name are in Sheets("Ref").Range("C4:C18")

Comment: Hint: the name is `wkblist.Offset(,-1).Value`.

Comment: Ah ok, so in each loop I can ask the macro to copy and paste the name wkblist.Offset(,-1).Value

Answer (score 0):

Ta,

I'm not too sure what worksheet you want the names to be pasted; I assume the data WS in the code below. Also, I would set the wkb, ws, and dataws outside of the loop since they are or belong to "ThisWorkbook". Not that it hurts to be inside of the loop, but you're just resetting them each time the loop runs.

The code below should find the range of rows that you just pasted into dataws. Then, it copies the names that are related to the wkblist in Col C into Col A of dataws.

```
Dim colARow, colBRow As Long

' Place code below after you paste the paths into Col B of the worksheet

' Find first blank in Col A
colARow = dataws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 

' Find last filled cell in Col B
colBRow = dataws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

dataws.Range("A" & colARow & ":A" & colBRow).Value = wkblist.Offset(0,-1).Value
```